# Simple conversion exercise, method does not return correct value

Tags: javascript

I just want to put the parameters in the Grade function and have it return their number grade converted into a letter grade.

```
function Grade(name, grade)  {
      this.name = name;

      this.grade = function(){
        if(grade >= 90){return "A"};
        else if (grade <90 && grade >=80){return "B"}
        else if(grade <80 && grade >= 70) {return "C"}
        else {return "fail"}
      };
    }
    var sally = new Grade("Sally", 72);
    console.log(sally.grade());
    console.log(sally.name);
```

Comment: hit f12 and go to the console tab. There is an error due to your semi-colon after the if line.

Comment: Thanks. It says unexpected token else so I don't quite understand.... but I will look more into using the console thank you :)

Comment: you can skip `grade <90 && ` because `grade` is after the first condition always smaller than 90.

Comment: that is a good point! thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the semicolon from `if(grade >= 90){return "A"}` line.

Also, for future reference (and debugging) you can use an online tool like JSFiddle.net to test and debug your javascript code.  As others have mentioned in comments, pressing *F12* in your browser will bring up developer tools.  The console will tell you if there are any errors.

Comment: Thank you. One more question.. what Sass is for CSS is there something like that for javascript?

Comment: If you're looking for languages that compile to javascript and  your familiar with java -- gwtproject.org might be your thing.  Otherwise there is some reading here: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/list-of-languages-that-compile-to-js.. IMHO -- I'd learn JS first, before jumping to one of these tools.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I don't at the moment know how to read the console's error signals as it doesn't explicitly say "semicolon after if statement" but I will have to learn that asap :)